# Why's my input box behaving in a weird way in terms of user input?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, redux, react-redux

I'm confused as to why I can't type anything in `<input onChange={this.handleArticleId} value={this.props.articleIdValue} placeholder="article id"/>`.  If I do type something, and click `submit`, only then does the letter appear in the input box.  The type of behavior I've never seen before.

What am I doing wrong & how can I fix this?

Here's `SearchArticle`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actionType from '../../store/actions/actions';

class SearchArticle extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            flag: false,
            idVal: '',
            cityCodeval: ''
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleArticleId = this.handleArticleId.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("IDValue --> " + this.state.idVal);
        this.props.articleIdValueRedux(this.state.idVal);
    }

    handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
        this.props.CityCodeReducerRedux(event.target.value);
    }

    handleArticleId = event => {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.setState({idVal: event.target.value});
    }

    displayName = () => {
           console.log("this.props.articleIdValue = " + this.props.articleIdValue);
           return(
               <div>
                   <p>author name: {this.props.authorNameValue}</p>
                   <p>article text: {this.props.storyTextValue}</p>
               </div>
           );
       }


    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.props.cityCodeValue} type="text" placeholder="city code"/>
                    <input onChange={this.handleArticleId} value={this.props.articleIdValue} placeholder="article id"/>
                    <button type="submit" value="Search">Submit</button>
                    {this.state.flag ? this.displayName() : null}
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        cityCodeValue: state.cityCodeValue.cityCodeValue,
        authorNameValue: state.authorNameValue.authorNameValue,
        articleIdValue: state.articleIdValue.articleIdValue,
        storyTextValue: state.storyTextValue.storyTextValue
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        CityCodeReducerRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.CITY_CODE_VALUE, value}),
        articleIdValueRedux: (value) => dispatch({type: actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE, value})
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchArticle);
```

Here's `ArticleIdReducer`

```
import * as actionType from './actions/actions';

const initialState = {
    articleIdValue: ''
};

const ArticleIdReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionType.ARTICLE_ID_VALUE:
            return {
                ...state,
                articleIdValue: action.value
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default ArticleIdReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are updating the local component state with `handleArticleId` but using `this.props.articleIdValue` for the value.

Either use a value from the local state or lift the state up and pass the handler to the parent.

I see you are using `redux` so you'll need to store the value in the `redux` store and create the relevant action and reducer for it.

Answer (score 1):

```
handleArticleId = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.setState({idVal: event.target.value});
    // You should probably be calling your this.props.articleIdValueRedux method here
}
```

You're not updating your redux state when `articleId` changes, only the internal component state (and retrieving the value from the redux store state to show in the input, which isn't updated)

Comment: Thank you.  Tried out your suggestion and it worked.  But I have 1 question.  Is the use of redux throughout my code efficient?  In other words, is how I'm using redux throughout my code good practice?

Comment: Personally, for forms, I maintain the state of the form inside the component, and once the submit button is clicked I send the information up to the reducers to do whatever they need to do.

When using a form that can also pre-load the information it contains, I use `componentDidMount` to map the props passed to it into the state. So the only thing I use in the inputs are the component's state, which is derived from the props initially passed to it

Comment: That being said, if your aim is to go for zero state in your components, you did handle it well